# php echo html tags that contain a variable to be defined later

Tags: php, html, echo

I generate buttons for each element of my database and each button contains a currentSlide() Function which i need to define the slider i want it to open predefined. I am using an array $buttonnums and define each element as "-1" but i want to define it later to another number and apply the change to the html in the same way we say class = " < ?php $var ? >" and afterwards we set the $var to something.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($buttonnums,"-1");
            end($buttonnums);
            echo "<button class=\"tablinks\" onclick=\"OpenCoffeeType(event,". $row["id"]."); currentSlide(<?php echo \$buttonnums[".key($buttonnums)."]?>)\"";
            if($count===0)
            {
                echo " id=\"defaultOpen\"";
                $count++;
            }
        echo ">". $row["title"]. " </button>";
    }
```

and afterwards i set their values here:

```
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if ($count===0)
                    {
                        $buttonnums[$count2] = $counter;
                    }
                    echo "<span class=\"dot periexomenakatigorias\"  onclick=\"currentSlide(".$counter.")\">".$row2["title"]."</span>";
                    $counter++;
                }
```

The result I get is currentSlide(<php echo $buttonnums[0]?>) instead of getting each time the value of $buttonnums[0]. I upload a picture too [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vY6H.png) to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` command is wrong. You `echo` another `<?PHP` tag with another `echo`. You should `echo` the actual variable instead.

```
echo "<button class=\"tablinks\" onclick=\"OpenCoffeeType(event,". $row["id"]."); currentSlide(<?php echo \$buttonnums[".key($buttonnums)."]?>)\"";
```

Should be something like this

```
echo "<button class=\"tablinks\" onclick=\"OpenCoffeeType(event,". $row["id"]."); currentSlide(.'$buttonnums[".key($buttonnums)."]'.)\"";
```

Comment: I tried to do it like this and it only get's the first value. When I try to change my variable to 1 from -1 the html keeps holding -1.

Comment: Who is $count2? Do you have a Github page for the project? Seeing the whole thing may help. You don't seem to update $buttonnums[0] but rather $buttonnums[$count2]. Yet you print $buttonnums[0];

Comment: hello i just added the project to github but it still won't run properly because it requires a database but hope you can understand more thing from there.
https://github.com/NeofytosKonstantinidis/phptest/tree/master